# "Connection has been closed" in Spring app after returning from suspend

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm using spring security, which uses jdbcTemplate in some bean xml configs. When I put my development laptop to sleep, and start working again later, I get "This connection has been closed" when trying to resume testing the app.

The only way I know how to recover is by tediously restarting the local server, which connects to the DB (postgreSQL) over the internet.

Is there some way to make the app re-establish the jdbc connection after coming back from suspend (or long absence?) instead of showing the connection error repeatedly and never re-establishing a connection?

my security-context.xml looks like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/upload" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login-error"/>
        <remember-me/>
        <logout />
    </http>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and my database-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />

</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
</bean>
</beans>
```

I don't like these XML configurations because I'd rather have programmatic control over the app, but I wasn't the one who chose and designed the app's architecture, so it's what I'm working with. If we weren't using XML-based configuration, I'd be able to programmatically check for the erroneous connection and reestablish it easily.

How might I get the app to re-establish connections after returning from suspend (or long periods of absence?) with an XML-based configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the connection string with autoReconnect=true. This is a property of the URL connection string, which works at the driver level. You need to change the connection string in the data source configuration. The URL below is used in case of mysql. Postgres must be having some way to do this.

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB?autoReconnect=true"
```

Or you can increase timeout in postgres configuration files.

Comment: THanks for the suggestion! I tried doing `url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDB?autoReconnect=true"` but it doesn't seem to work.